# Passing HTML element into React Component before Element is Rendered

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

If we have the React component `Foo` that instantiates the class `Bar` and we need to pass the `HTMLCollection` element with ID `foo` into `Bar`, how can it be done?

`Bar.js` should ideally remained unchanged.

I tried the following:

**Foo.js**

```
import Bar from './Bar';

const Foo = () => {
    const elem = document.getElementById('foo');
    const bar = new Bar(elem, {});

  return (
    <div id="foo">
    </div>
  );
};

export default Foo;
```

**Bar.js**

```
export default class Bar {
    constructor(domElement, config = {}) {
      console.log(domElement);  // null
      console.log(domElement.getElementsByClassName('bar'));  // null
    }
  }
```

but `domElement` is always `null`, maybe because when we run `document.getElementById`, the element `div#foo` has not been rendered yet.

---

Also tried the using `useRef`:

**Foo.js**

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import Bar from './Bar';

const Foo = () => {
  const elemRef = useRef(null);
  const bar = new Bar(elemRef, {});

  return (
    <div id="foo" ref={elemRef}>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Foo;
```

**Bar.js**

```
export default class Bar {
    constructor(domElement, config = {}) {
      console.log(domElement);  // {current: null}
      console.log(domElement.getElementsByClassName('bar'));  // Uncaught TypeError: domElement.getElementsByClassName is not a function
    }
}
```

but getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: domElement.getElementsByClassName is not a function

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) hook which fires synchronously after all DOM mutations

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const elem = document.getElementById("foo");
    const bar = new Bar(elem, {});
  }, []);
```